# Is is possible to prove that two systems of axioms are equivalent

Tags: axioms, peano-axioms, axiomatic-geometry

The question is self explanatory. Is it possible to prove that two systems of axioms in two very different branches of math are equivalent? Is there a textbook to help me? Thanks!!

Comment: yes check [reverse mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_mathematics) and mathematical logic (among others)

Answer (score 1):

We answer a related question that removes the "two very different branches of math" part. Is there an algorithm which, given as input two recursive sets $A$ and $B$ of axioms, will determine whether or not $A$ and $B$ are equivalent?

The answer is no. For let $A$ be the first-order Peano axioms, and let $B$ be $A$ with the sentence $\varphi$ adjoined. Then such an algorithm would give a decision procedure for whether or not $\varphi$ is a theorem of first-order Peano arithmetic. But it is well-known that there is no such algorithm.

Peano arithmetic can be replaced by other *undecidable theories*, including finitely axiomatized ones. Most simply, we can look at the theory over the language that has a single binary predicate symbol $P$ and *no axioms*. So $A$ is the empty set. For it is known that there is no algorithm for determining whether or not a sentence is a theorem of the "empty" theory. (This theorem can be obtained from the undecidability of a certain version of arithmetic, or alternately from the theory of Turing machines.)

Comment: The set of logical validities in most signatures is already undecidable, of course; the empty theory is an undecidable theory.

Comment: You just blew my mind. Could you clarify the "it is well known" part?

Comment: You might want to look for undecidable problems on Wikipedia, or Tarski's *Undecidable Theories*. These include the pure predicate calculus with a single binary relation. The bundle of initial results is usually credited to Godel, Turing, and Church.

Comment: @sarafi, "it is well known" is a result of Goedel (and others) that there are sentences (propositions) of (for example) Peano Arithmetic which are **undecidable**, thus there is no general algorithm, however for some cases the comment on reverse mathematics does just that

Answer (score 1):

in principle it should be possible

first of all you need a dictionary between the two systems to relate the terms in the first system to the terms in the other.

then you need to prove that axioms of system 1 are theorems (provable) in system 2

and  you need to prove that axioms of system 2 are theorems (provable) in system 1

good luck